# Binding horizontal scroll in a function with feedkeys

Tags: vim-windows, functions

I'm trying to create a function to make editing TSV files easier. The function changes spacing settings, turns off wrapping, and creates a 1 row tall split at the top so that the column headers are always visible.

However I'm having trouble getting the two windows to bind on horizontal scroll. I can get them to bind when executing the commands manually but it doesn't work when I call the function.

```
fun! TSV()
  execute "setlocal nowrap"
  execute "setlocal noexpandtab"
  execute "setlocal shiftwidth=20"
  execute "setlocal softtabstop=20"
  execute "setlocal tabstop=20"
  " always visible header
  execute "sp"
  execute "0"
  call feedkeys("\<C-W>K")
  call feedkeys("1\<C-W>_")
  call feedkeys("\<C-W>j")
  " bind horizontal scrolling
  execute "set scrollopt=hor"
  execute "set scrollbind"
  call feedkeys("\<C-W>k")
  execute "set scrollbind"
  call feedkeys("\<C-W>j")
endfun
```

Comment: You probably don’t need many of those execute statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your `feedkeys()` invocations write keys in the typeahead buffer, but they're not pressed immediately. Vim probably waits for the whole mapping and the function it calls to be processed.
You can tell `feedkeys()` to make Vim press the keys immediately by passing it the `x` flag (see `:h feedkeys()`).
You may also want to pass the `n` flag to prevent custom mapping from interfering:

So, instead of writing:

```
call feedkeys("\<C-W>K")
```

You would write:

```
call feedkeys("\<C-W>K", 'nx')
```

But usually, to execute commands which affect windows, you use `:wincmd`:

```
call feedkeys("\<C-W>K", 'nx')
→
wincmd K

call feedkeys("1\<C-W>_", 'nx')
→
1wincmd _

call feedkeys("\<C-W>j", 'nx')
→
wincmd j

call feedkeys("\<C-W>k", 'nx')
→
wincmd k
```

So, you could try this function:

```
fun! TSV()
    setlocal nowrap
    setlocal noexpandtab
    setlocal shiftwidth=20
    setlocal softtabstop=20
    setlocal tabstop=20
    " always visible header
    sp
    0
    wincmd K
    1wincmd _
    wincmd j
    " bind horizontal scrolling
    set scrollopt=hor
    set scrollbind
    wincmd k
    set scrollbind
    wincmd j
endfun
```